# Restructure "did you mean x?" so that `x` is at the beginning

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I'm trying to find a sentence with an equivalent meaning to:

> did you mean x?

Where `x` is the first word of the sentence. This sentence is displayed when a user enters invalid input, suggesting an alternative.

Is it possible?

Comment: "Is x what you meant?" gets it a lot closer to the beginning of the sentence.

Comment: (Why? What are you really trying to do?)

Comment: @Drew It's a suggestion to fix a compilation error. The suggestion text appears directly under the original text (both in a monospaced font), so I'm trying to align the two.

Comment: X would compile here.

Answer (score 2):

> X was what you meant, wasn't it?

does the job of suggesting the alternative that was probably the original intention.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this one is a bit too long for my use case

Answer (score 1):

> X, you mean?

This is pretty casual, and can be a quick fix when someone makes a slip of the tongue.

> Sarah: "So I'm going to the mechanic tomorrow to get my hair cut."
>
> Alice: "Salon, you mean?"
>
> Sarah: "Oh, right. I'm going to the salon."

For a website form, this would only work if your overall pattern of communication is pretty casual.

Comment: This could work, I'll be using this for now. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I start to visualise a small alien with large ears with this construction. Like Yoda it sound to me!